# Thymeleaf. Server does not see templates directory, how can I point to it if I packaged app to jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, server, thymeleaf

I have a java Spring Boot application that uses Thymeleaf and Model in my Controller. Also I have `templates` directory in my resources where all `.html` pages are located.
My Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/frontView")
public class FrontController {
    private final CameraService cameraService;

    public FrontController(CameraService cameraService) {
        this.cameraService = cameraService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/firstCameraData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dataListFromFirstCamera(Model model) {
        cameraService.returnAllCars(model, "firstCamera");
        return "firstCamera.html";
    }
```

Part of .pom file that I think is the only useful for determining the issue

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>de.qaware.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>go-offline-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadoc>false</downloadJavadoc>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I don't have any configuration classes for my application or thymeleaf - the problem I stuck with - locally everything works just fine.
My application is running locally on Tomcat and I can see `localhost:8080/frontView/firstCameraData` page just fine, but after deploying my application on server in `.jar` file I'm getting `404 page not found`

I think that the problem is - when my application is running on server it does not see `resources/templates` directory. I know that it maybe could be solved by repackaging the application in `.war` and putting my .html files in `webapp` directory, but I don't want this. Are there any solutions that will allow me to let the server see that directory being in `.jar` format?

Comment: Add logging for `org.springframework.web: DEBUG` and check that your controller mapping is getting installed.

Comment: You were right! I added logging level DEBUG for org.springframework.web and didn't see a thing about my FrontController in logs even after calling its methods. I also added  method that returns simple string in FrontController and also getting "404 not found" from it. Do you have any advice how can I solve my problem? 
I have @RestController in my application that works just fine, but for the Thymeleaf to work it should be controller, so I can't change that

Answer (score 1):

Actually that wasn't the problem of packaging in `.jar` or `.war`.
I had the helm configured, and in my `values.yaml` I had the default path...

```
corePath: /core
```

So, for my controller to work it should be done like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/core/frontView")
public class FrontController {
    private final CameraService cameraService;

    public FrontController(CameraService cameraService) {
        this.cameraService = cameraService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/firstCameraData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String dataListFromFirstCamera(Model model) {
        cameraService.returnAllCars(model, "firstCamera");
        return "firstCamera.html";
    }
```

And after that the correct link would be `http://*****/core/frontView/firstCameraData`

Many thanks to @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic for help